# JQuery UI Tabs: Add tab at the second position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css-selectors, jquery-ui-tabs

I am having trouble to add a tab between the first and second tab.

I have a button when it is pressed a new tab with demo content should appear between the first and the second tab.

This is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/schludi/egpwnhLq/30/

When I press the Add-Button the new tab with example content should appear between the first and the second tab.

```
$( function() {

var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();


// Actual addTab function: adds new tab using the input from the form above.
function addTab() {
  var li = $("<li><a href='#tabs-2'>OP(s)</a></li>");

  tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav").append( li );
  tabs.append( "<div id='tabs-3'>This should appear between first and second.</div>" );
  tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
}

// AddTab button: just opens the dialog
$( "#add_tab" )
  .button()
  .on( "click", function() {
          addTab();
  });
```

Comment: you are using append(). append will add tab at the end.

Comment: Hi! Yes, what should i use in jquery ui tabs instead to add a tab between the first and the second tab? My problem is, when i add it manually some styles aren't on the li-Tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.append()` will always insert content at the end of the selected element, as a child of that element.

What you want to do is find the first tab entry and insert something directly after it (but not as a child of it). For this you can make use of the CSS `:first-child` selector and the jQuery `.after()` method:

```
function addTab() {
  var li = $("<li><a href='#tabs-3'>OP(s)</a></li>");
  tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav li:first-child").after( li ); //changed this line
  tabs.append( "<div id='tabs-3'>This should appear between first and second</div>" );
  tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/egpwnhLq/42/ for a working demo.

See https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/ and http://api.jquery.com/after/ for documentation of the selector and method used.

Comment: A this is exactly i was searching for. Thank you